# How much data can I allocate on heap in codechef problems?

Tags: allocation

What is the maximum amount of data I can allocate in a solution in codechef ?

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it is about the rules of a programming competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codechef uses SPOJ servers. The new problems use Cube cluster, so as mentioned here- http://www.spoj.com/clusters/ memory limit is 1536 MB. Which means you have plenty of memory available on heap (a large portion of total memory) and need not worry for any reasonable solution.